# how to handle multiple objects with same name in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, blender

I'm making a simple game in Blender game engine. I have some obstacles in a separate layer. I then put them in front of a character using `addObject`.
When that happens, the new object has the exact same name as the original object on another layer.

I want to know how I can access that object. It would also help if there's a way to rename the object upon creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

Instead of just calling the object's name (which vill always access the original object on seperate layer) I used `scene.objects['object']`. So the game access the object in the current layer.